# Refresh Excel data from command line

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have an Excel sheet with PowerQuery connecting via ODBC to SAP Data Source.

Usually, I manually click "Refresh All" to refresh data. To automate this, I wrote a Python script to refresh the sheet automatically. It has some issues.

Is there a way to execute this Refresh All command from command line?

Code tried in Python:

```
 xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
 wb = xlapp.workbooks.open(File1.xlsx)
 wb.RefreshAll()
wb.SaveAs(File2.xlsx)
```

Comment: From within VBA you can refresh all conections using `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll`. Are you using xlwings in python?

Comment: You should show your code, so we can help you with this. Furthermore *"It has some issues"* is no useful error description.

Comment: @M.Getrost No, I did not use XLWings. I just created a WorkBook object and executed something like: wb.Refresh. It is not refreshing.

Comment: @M.Getrost Is there a way to invoke this VBA command you mentioned via Python or any programming language ?

Comment: Yes. check out xlwings. It's an python package. you can refresh your connections with something like this: `import xlwings as xw` `app = xw.App()` `wb = xw.Book('pathtoFile')` `wb.api.RefreshAll()`

Comment: The easiest way in Windows to access an Excel Sheet is probably VBScript because it is very similar to VBA and can be run without having to install anything besides Excel.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Added code.

Comment: @M.Getrost Please add as an answer, so that I can try and mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xlwings` in python. It's probably the best Excel-Library in Python. your code could look like this:

```
import xlwings as xw

app = xw.App()

wb = xw.Book('pathToFile')
wb.api.RefreshAll()
```

Another option, as PEH mentioned, would be to use a VBScript. Open an txt-Editor copy in this Code:

```
Dim ObjExcel, ObjWB
Set ObjExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set ObjWB = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("pathToFile")
ObjWB.RefreshAll

Set ObjWB = Nothing
Set ObjExcel = Nothing
```

save as fileName.vbs 
Run the VBScript to update the connections.